# Connect to Mysql from Java securely?

Tags: java, mysql

Hello there I am curious how I can link to mysql from java securely. The only thing I cant figure out is how to keep the password out of plain text! Any help is great.

Comment: *"I am curious how I can link to mysql from java securely."*  From what?  A client side desktop application, a servlet, a shoebox?

Comment: It will connect a java plugin to our private mysql server and be constantly communicating between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html) of the MySQL Connector/J 8.0 documentation explains how to secure a JDBC connection using SSL and a client certificate.  That way, you won't need to use a password at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) for the database connection.  As far as

> keep the password out of plain text

how do expect on connecting to it if there is plain-text password somewhere? I'd say just use a generated 128bit password, and encrypt *that*.  maybe have a properties file that your program loads that is not part of the project, then fetch it from there?

Another alternative would just to use SSH authentication which would bypass the password entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation of [MessageDigest Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html):

> This MessageDigest class provides applications the functionality of a
>   message digest algorithm, such as MD5 or SHA. Message digests are
>   secure one-way hash functions that take arbitrary-sized data and
>   output a fixed-length hash value.

Call `getInstance("MD5")` to get an MD5 message digest you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's not really that hard. Simply download MYSQL Connector, add it to your path and then fire a PreparedStatement on it, as in :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?"
          + "user=myusername&password=mypassword");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect
      .prepareStatement("select * from employees");
 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()) {
  //display text
}
preparedStatement.close();
connect.close();
```

You can then do something like a resultSet.getString() or so to get the value required and them cast them into whatever you want, in case there are too many columns and the Tables are volatile. If they aren't, then you can use getInteger(), getDouble() etc.

Look up more over here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

Now, you can use a hashing strategy to hash i.e. mask your password. You can have this code in another package that you current code links to to obtain the values.

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm